# Awkward CursorAdaptor view recycling

Tags: android

I'm using a ResourceCursorAdapter to display a list of downloads from
a ContentProvider that track's my application's downloads -- modeled
after Android's DownloadProvider.

The problem is that when a download is actively running it frequently
calls bind view--every few seconds--to update a download progress bar,
with a view object that is NOT currently associated with a given
item/cursor position.  Thus, bind view is constantly recycling and binding
view objects to different item/cursor positions (call it "flip-flopping").  Note, I only have one view type.

This is especially a problem if the user attempts to push a button on
one of the items while it's being bound to a different view object and
cursor position, which results in an event being fired for the wrong
data.

Does anyone have advice on how to minimize unnecessary view recycling, or not have the view objects flip-flop between positions?

This view object flip-flopping appears to only occur for the bottom and top list items (of the three on the screen), while the middle item/cursor remains tied to a single view object.

Thanks,
-Ivan